# Create click event from WPF MenuItem defined by a string

Tags: c#, wpf, string, menuitem

I define parts of a menu with an array of string, and I want to automatically create click events for each of these. All of them are going to to the same thing, only a different parameter.

```
string[] goTos = new string[] { "First", "Second", "Third" };
```

When Initializing the window:

```
        foreach (string item in goTos)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem goTo = new System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem();
            goTo.Header = item;
            goTo.Name = "mnu" + item;
            mnuGoTo.Items.Add(goTo);
        }
```

How can I get click events for these?

Comment: Just add the event handler and within the event handler method determine which `MenuItem` called the handler by examining the `sender` parameter of your handler method.

Comment: Any idea how I can extract the header?

Comment: The `sender` object passed to your handler method is the `MenuItem` object. So if you use `(sender as MenuItem).Header` you've got all you want. (You may need to add a check for null if the handler might get called from other controls too.)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can try this

```
   string[] goTos = new string[] { "First", "Second", "Third" };
        foreach (string item in goTos)
        {
           System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem goTo = new   System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem();
            goTo.Header = item;
            goTo.Name = "mnu" + item;
            goTo.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(goTo_Click);
            mnuGoTo.Items.Add(goTo);
        }

    }

    void goTo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if they are "going to to the same thing"

i suggest you use

```
<MenuItem Name="MenuItems" Header="Item1">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
           <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
               <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}"MethodName="Event"/>
          </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</MenuItem>
```

on your View and add the event Method to your Viewmodel

if you do not use MVVM for your project, this is the perfect time to learn.

Comment: I'll definitly look into it!

Comment: Make a method in your Viewmodel for the MethodName.